# MySQL: Trigger error: #1193 - Unknown system variable 'PurchasePrice'

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1193

I'm trying to create a trigger where if someone says they have a discount code, the purchaseprice of their ticket drops by $10.

I ran the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER alterPurchasePrice AFTER INSERT ON CustomerOrders FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN IF DiscountCode = 'yes' THEN SET PurchasePrice = Cost - 10 END$$
```

But got the error:

```
#1193 - Unknown system variable 'PurchasePrice'
```

However, I have that column in my table. So I don't understand why it's not recognizing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to identify the column as coming from a table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER alterPurchasePrice
    BEFORE INSERT ON CustomerOrders
     FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF new.DiscountCode = 'yes' THEN
        SET new.PurchasePrice = new.Cost - 10;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you want to re-set the value, it  should be a before-insert trigger.

Comment: When I run that I get:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF END' at line 7 . I tried it with just END$$ but get the same error.

Comment: Any thoughts on why it would still error out after the change?

Comment: @DJPharaohCHS . . . Added a semicolon to the `END IF`.

Answer (score -2):

CREATE TRIGGER alterPurchasePrice AFTER INSERT ON CustomerOrders FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN IF NEW.DiscountCode = 'yes' THEN SET NEW.PurchasePrice = Cost - 10 END$$

You didn't use NEW keyword. Kindly use it

Comment: It would be immensely helpful if you remembered to format your code  as... code ;)

Maybe also highlight your additions with bold, so they are easier to spot.

Comment: How is this answer different/better from the accepted one? Try to avoid bumping up old posts, especially the ones with accepted answers.